# If there's match append text to the beginning of the next line

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, grep

I have a file like this

```
from a
b
to c
d
from e
f
from g
h
to i
j
```

If there's match for `from`, add `to` to the beginning of the next line. If there's a match for `to`, add `from` to the beginning of the next line. The output should be like this

```
from a
to b
to c
from d
from e
to f
from g
to h
to i
from j
```

Can this be done using any unix commands?

I have tried paste command to merge every 2 lines and then using sed. Something like this. But it's definitely wrong. Also, I don't know how to split it back again.

`paste -d - - <file> | sed "s/\(^from.*\)/\1 to/" | sed "s/\(^to.*\)/\1 from/"`

I think there should be an easier solution to this compared to what I'm doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sed` :

```
sed '/^from/{n;s/^/to /;b};/^to/{n;s/^/from /}'
```

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/3u1xlT).

Comment: ooh I got it. Nice one

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '{if ($1 ~ /^(from|to)$/) dir=$1; else $0=(dir=="from" ? "to" : "from") OFS $0} 1' file
from a
to b
to c
from d
from e
to f
from g
to h
to i
from j
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work :

```
awk '
    #Before reading the file I build a dictionary that links "from" keywoard to "to" value and inversally
    BEGIN{kw["from"]="to"; kw["to"]="from"}
    #If the first word of the line is a key of my dictionary (to or from), I save the first word in k variable and print the line
    $1 in kw{k=$1;print;next} 
    #Else I add the "opposite" of k at the beginning of the line
    {print kw[k], $0} 
' <input>
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks! BTW, if possible can you just in short explain the code. Sorry, I'm a beginner to awk and have no idea.

Comment: @Arteezy sure I added comments

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
{
  val=prev=="from" && $0 !~ /to/?"to "$0:prev=="to" && $0 !~/from/?"from "$0:$0
  prev=$1
  $0=val
}
1
'  Input_file
```